# Android Phone Disconnect Reconnect On Windows on Different Port

Tags: windows-10, usb, android

Recently all 3 of my front port started acting weird when connecting my android via cable

Port One:

```
Charges my phone, but doesn't connect or even set off the beeping sound
```

Port Two:

```
Charges my phone and connect to the android, but disconnect and reconnect every few seconds
```

Port Three:

```
Charges my phone and connect to the android, but disconnect every few minutes ( found out from after failing to transfer photos )
```

This was all recently this week as weeks prior i can regularly use these ports no problem, I'm worried it's either my front port suddenly break or windows acting up

**Things I've tried** :

- Check if the cable work by using my Macbook air ( works completely fine )
- Check my phones port by testing the cable on friend's phone and mine on a wall charger ( works completely fine )
- Tried using [Universal ADB Driver](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/) ( Still not able to connect )
- Tried using [fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows) ( Still not able to connect )
- Restarting my pc ( still not able to connect )
- Check my pc's front port by using my mouse and gamepad ( works completely fine )
- Change the cable I've used several times ( Still the problem exist )

I've been searching for the answer for the past 10 hours as i need to transfer files from my android to my pc on a daily basis (which now i'm using my macbook)

**Edit**

Additional information

- Which phone do you use (respectively does it use USB2 or USB3)?
  Answer : Android Samsung A50 and Android Samsung Galaxy Note 8 both tested on all 3 with port 3 being USB 3.0
- Have you tried the USB ports on the back of the computer that directly resides on the mainboard? Answer : I haven't as it's current filled with other peripherals
- How long is the used USB cable?
  Answer : 1 meter
- What mainboard (CPU+chipset) is used by your PC? Answer : CPU : AMD Ryzen 7 x3800 and MOBO: B450M

Comment: Which phone do you use (respectively does it use USB2 or USB3)? Have you tried the USB ports on the back of the computer that directly resides on the mainboard? How long is the used USB cable? What mainboard (CPU+chipset) is used by your PC?

Comment: Which phone do you use (respectively does it use USB2 or USB3)?
Answer : Android Samsung A50 and Android Samsung Galaxy Note 8 both tested on all 3 with port 3 being USB 3.0
Have you tried the USB ports on the back of the computer that directly resides on the mainboard?
Answer : I haven't as it's current filled with other peripherals
How long is the used USB cable?
Answer : 1 meter
What mainboard (CPU+chipset) is used by your PC?
Answer : CPU : AMD Ryzen 7 x3800 and MOBO: B450M

Comment: The USB2/3 question was more focusing on the phones because using a USB3 port on PC side has no effect if the phone only uses USB2. Furthermore for long answers and interesting additional information it would be better to edit your question and include that info there. Then users don't have to read all the comments for important additional info...

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the details to the main question

Comment: There is a known problem with USB on Ryzen CPUs, may be this is also the main problem in your case: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/amd-suggest-possible-fixes-for-usb-connectivity-issues

Comment: I would assume that if it wasn't for the fact that my problem exist this week and the article was posted 2 months ago, all 3 of my ports worked normally prior to this week

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124131/discussion-between-richard-yulis-and-robert).

Comment: I would install the official drivers for those models from Samsung>>>https://samsungusbdrivers.me/samsung-galaxy-a50-usb-drivers-download  >>>>>http://www.samsungdrivers.net/samsung-galaxy-note8-driver-software/

Comment: Problem still persist,but now port 3 somehow turns worst after that driver installation instead of a few minutes now it's a few seconds like port 2